# How to get immediate parent category of WooCommerce product?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a hierarchical custom tax (woocom products) and I am trying to build some breadcrumbs. I found `get_ancestors()` and am thinking of using that for the terms, but once I get down to a product I get lost. How to get the immediate top category (that is the list of products) it belongs to?

```
All Categories  **term ID 192**
-Sub Cat One  **term id 204**
-- Sub Cat Two (products listed out here) **term id 207**
--- Product
```

Here is the code I put together trying to figure this out, just logs out the results for now,

```
function build_breadcrumbs( $product_cat_id, $type ) {

    if( 'product' === $type ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms($product_cat_id, 'product_cat');
        error_log( print_r(  $terms, true ) );
    }
    else {
        $ancestors = get_ancestors($product_cat_id, $type);
        error_log( print_r(  $ancestors, true ) );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to build a breadcrumb. This will list out all product categories in hierarchical order.

```
function cd_get_term_parents( $id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = ' >> ', $nicename = false, $visited = array() ) {
    $chain = '';
    $parent = &get_term( $id, $taxonomy );
    if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) )
            return $parent;

    if ( $nicename ) {
            $name = $parent->slug;
    } else {
            $name = $parent->name;
    }

    if ( $parent->parent && ( $parent->parent != $parent->term_id ) && !in_array( $parent->parent, $visited ) ) {
            $visited[] = $parent->parent;
            $chain .= cd_get_term_parents( $parent->parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited );
    }

    if ( $link ) {
            $chain .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $parent, $taxonomy ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( _e( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name ) ) . '">'.$parent->name.'</a>' . $separator;
    } else {
            $chain .= $name.$separator;
    }
    return $chain;
}
```